# Graphql query from array object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, graphiti-js

I have a mongoose schema like this:

```
var MoviesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  collections: [String]
});

var Movie = mongoose.model('Movie', MovieSchema);
```

I'm using `graphiti` to generate the graphql schema automatically. I'm able to query the data using `name`, however I'm unable to query using `collections` since the type is an array.

For instance, this works:

```
{
  movies(name: "Kabali") {
    name,
    collection
  }
}
```

however this doesn't work:

```
{
  movies(collection: "Hollywood") {
    name,
    collection
  }
}
```

Actually, the movies field doesn't even have the argument called `collection`.

Comment: Could you share your GraphQL schema as well? You show your mongoose schema and asks for a GraphQL solution. :/

Comment: @BjørnSørensen: As I mentioned, I haven't written graphql schema since it is automatically produced by graphiti js library. That is the reason I didn't put the graphql schema :)

Comment: Is the 'name' property its' primary key?

Comment: @KesemDavid , the 'name' is not a primary key. There is a property called _id which is a primary key